# Problems with a TP-Link adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, vmware, adapter

I got a TP-Link UE300 V.3 adapter for my Ubuntu 20.04, kernel version 5.13.0-35-generic and it doesn't work. I got "wired connected" and have 100MB/s. I tried `sudo dhclient -r` and `sudo dhclient` but it didn't work. I have Asus Vivobook S14/S15.
I'm trying to connect on a public network at school, so I can't do anything to the router. The cable is Cat5e. I tried to connect both the cable and adapter to a laptop with Windows 10 and it worked, so I guess the problem is my laptop.

`ifconfig`:

```
        inet 192.168.0.126  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::b6b0:24ff:fe15:7e13  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b4:b0:24:15:7e:13  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 982  bytes 108355 (108.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 569  bytes 50486 (50.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4200  bytes 398476 (398.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4200  bytes 398476 (398.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`sudo lshw -C network`:

```
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9462
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: c8:58:c0:9e:e6:f7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-35-generic firmware=63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.u latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:c431c000-c431ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: enxb4b024157e13
       serial: b4:b0:24:15:7e:13
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v2.15.0 (2021/04/15) duplex=full ip=192.168.0.126 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

`ping google.com`:

`ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

`route -n`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 enxb4b024157e13
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enxb4b024157e13
```

I got to specify that I tried to install the drivers manually from https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-usb-3-0-software (the Unix/Linux one) and from GIT too: https://github.com/JulAlx/TP-Link-UE300-UE330-Linux-Driver but it didn't work.
The input of `sudo make` for the driver of Realtek link I get `Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.` and unavailability of vmware.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Forgot to say that it worked few times when I let unplugged the laptop for more than 20 minutes. After that it just stopped working when I unplugged it again and plugged it back.
I have no real experience with this.

EDIT2: As chilli555 said:

`ping -c3 8.8.8.8`:

```
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Net Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2031ms
```

`ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 mar 13  2022 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

Started the laptop now, after 4 hours with wired connection and no problems. Unplugged it and plugged it back and doesn't work again.

EDIT3:
No idea why there are different adressess. This is the answer of  `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` with the ethernet network working:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=112 time=17.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=112 time=17.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=112 time=17.6 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 17.296/17.398/17.582/0.130 ms
```

What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Because the driver is installed and it works intermittently, this sounds more like a networking issue than a driver issue

Comment: Please edit your  question to show the result of the terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and also: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I wonder why the pings came from 192.168.0.1. Isn't that your router address? It appears that the USB ethernet is x.126.